# Alfresco submit form

Tags: javascript, button, submit, alfresco, freemarker

When i validate the form on alfresco with the submit button, the process return with the previous url.
I would submit my form and then go to one url i have on javascript.

If you cant help thank you.

i have try this without success :

< input onclick="window.location.href = 'http://test.test.test';" type="submit" value="Submit request" />

and this one doesn t work too :

< button type="button" value="submit" onclick="redirect to url test">

Comment: To help others help, you need a good title, a good question. Also you want to put the code into code markup. Good luck!

Comment: Hello, i have found the solution, it s on alfresco.js line 11318 just change document.referrer
                 else
                  {
                     document.location.href = document.referrer;
                  }
               }

Answer (score 1):

The `submission-url` allows the action attribute of the generated form to be overridden so that the contents of the form can be submitted to any arbitrary URL. You will require a custom form template(ftl) and js along with your form if you want any additional customization with the OOTB forms processing.

```
  <#if form.mode != "view">
         <form id="${formId}" method="${form.method}" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="${form.enctype}" action="${form.submissionUrl}">
      </#if>
```

Please refer the below link for additional information.

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/forms-custom-formtemplate.html

Comment: I have a special form with special JS inside. But you can t change action="${form.submissionUrl}">
Or i don t know how. your doc doesn t help for the submit but can help for create form and declare the form.
Thank you anyway